# Firestore collectionReference returns all documents

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore to query some documents with a certain id. This is my structure:

EDIT: SCREENSHOT AND DESCRIPTION ADDED JUST AFTER THIS LINE:

`generatedId` and `id` have the same value. I have a list of these "id" and I want to search the `public_messages` collection to return a list of items which my provided list of "id".

[image: firestore structure]

```
root
----- public_messages
---------- generatedId
-------------------- name
-------------------- id  
---------- generatedId
-------------------- name
-------------------- id  
----- other data
```

I am using the following code to query the messages with a certain id:

```
 ArrayList<String> keys ... (this has some keys)

    CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("public_messages");

    for (String id : keys) {
        collectionReference.whereEqualTo("id", id);
    }

    collectionReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int count = 0;
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    count++;
                }
                loog("total messages = " + count);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

In `onComplete`, the variable `task.getResult()` returns all the documents in the said collection. Consequently, the variable `count` represents the total number of documents in the said collection.

I want to only query the results with the specified ids. The number of ids can exceed 10 (which is apparently the limit set by Google, and which limit I was trying to evade by using a for-loop). What should I do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact filtering that you want to get.

Comment: screenshot and description added.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it totally. So you have list of ids and you want to get all documents that correspond with all those ids? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. And the number of ids exceed 10. Alternatively, I am thinking of getting each message individually using DocumentReference but this will drastically increase the number of individual get() commands (and the risk of failure also increases). So I want to make a solution where I can search all of them in one go.

Comment: I understand now. Ok, I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this problem is to use Tasks's [whenAllSuccess(Collection> tasks)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html):

> Returns a Task with a list of Task results that completes successfully when all of the specified Tasks complete successfully.

Like in the following lines of code:

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("public_messages");
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>(); //Contains your keys
ArrayList<Task<QuerySnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (String id : ids) {
    Task<QuerySnapshot> task = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("id", id).get();
    tasks.add(task);
}

Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
        //Do what you need to do with your list
        for (Object object : list) {
            PublicMessage publicMessage = ((DocumentSnapshot) object).toObject(PublicMessage.class);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "Finished getting all " + list.size() + " documents");
    }
});
```

When the `onSuccess()` fires, you'll be sure that you've got absolutely all documents.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. Though I had to change the for-loop code to get the DocumentSnapshot using ```DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = ((QuerySnapshot) object).getDocuments().get(0);```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

CollectionReference collectionReference =

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("public_messages").whereIn("id", keys);

collectionReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(..);
```

Comment: wherein requires a list, and even if I use a list, it returns all the documents

Comment: you will get all the documents with the ids you provide in the ids list

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
// getting a reference to the collection
const collectionRef = collection(getFirestore(), 'COLLECTION-NAME');

//get the documents from the collection by its ref.
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);

// now you can run for each document with simple loop 
querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
  console.log(document.id, ' => ', document.data());
});
```